# Jquery mobile Deeplinking (sort of)

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using multi-page `jquery` mobile and need to create a link from one "page" to content on another "page".

Am I able to do it straight through `<a>` or do I need to add additional code?

Code :

```
<body>
  <div style="min-height: 880px;" class="ui-page ui-body-c" data-role="page" id="Welcome"
  tabindex="0" data-url="Welcome">
    <!--- some content here =-->
    <!--- further down the "page" link =-->
    <a class="ui-link" href="#abstractday1" data-ajax="false">Abstract Day 1</a> 
    <!--- link that has been shortened just to a to save time =-->
  </div>

  <div style="min-height: 880px;" class="ui-page ui-body-c" data-role="page" id=
  "Abstract" tabindex="0" data-url="Abstract">
    <!--- further down the "page" where i want to goto =-->
    <!--- below is where I want to go from welcome link =-->
    <a class="ui-link" name="abstractday1"></a>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Figured the answer out with some time to think about it.

I'll add the answer for others to use.

Script / js :

```
function myFunction(val) {
    setTimeout( function(){

  window.location.href = ""+ val +"";

}   , 1000 );
}
```

link:

```
<a class="ui-link" href="#Abstract" onclick="myFunction('#abstractday1')" data-ajax="false">Abstract Day 1</a>
```

Happy Coding :)